# root chinese tablet Twrp is the only way?

Tags: rooting, 6.0-marshmallow, twrp

Hi everyone I hope you are safe in this time's ! and I'm tring to do root into a chinese tablet

[image]

[image]
[image]

It is a nice piece i can vnc to my pc's or ssh and control by kdeconnect or use yatze etc i like it but i will love it whit cyanogenmod but that it is such a task to get it done just by me I'm starting for get it rooted now i have manage to get the scarttedfile and pull averything from.

[image]

there you can see userdata.img system.img etc. The mnt folder i place it, to mount system.img on it like

`mount -o loop system.img mnt`

And then modify the system and then flash it back again into whit SP_FLASH_TOOL it is almost the same as have root on it but i need place a swap file and made swapon probably I could doit from the file recovery.fstab wich cointain

```
    # mount point   fstype      device          [device2]

/boot       emmc        boot
/cache      ext4        /dev/block/mmcblk0p4
/data       ext4        /dev/block/mmcblk0p5
/misc       emmc        misc
/recovery   emmc        recovery
/sdcard     vfat        /dev/block/mmcblk0p6
/system     ext4        /dev/block/mmcblk0p3
```

I'm not sure about i will try but why? i have come here it is to see if some one could help me to either way build twrp for this devices or let me know how to place the magestik app on the system.img to do root hopefully some one here knows how to do so since twrp what it does is that rigth ? Flash the app in to the system i just should place it into the /app folder

Comment: magisk is systemless root method, only patch boot.img with magisk manager apk

Comment: Oh yes i found it thank you @alecxs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I follow the instructions from magisk to patch the boot.img file quite easy as alecxs  suggested and it is done

[image]